# Join table order

Tags: sql, join

Query1: t1 left join t2 on **some condition** cross join t3 right join t4 on **some condition**

Query2: t1 left join t2 on **some condition** cross join t4 left join t3 on **some condition**

Will the result of these queries be the same or not?

Comment: It will be same

Comment: The results will be the same, but perhaps because of a slight of hand.  Since there is no `ON` condition in the final (third) join, this join is effectively a cross join.  So cross join 3, followed by 4 is the same as cross join 4, followed by 3.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, Post that as answer rather

Comment: we have on condition with every join in both the query @TimBiegeleisen

Q1: t1 left join t2 on <some condition>  cross join t3 right join t4  on <some condition>



Q2: t1 left join t2 on <some condition>  cross join t4 right join t3  on <some condition>

Comment: @PratapSinghRanawat You just invalidated my answer and changed your question.  Update your question and show us the real queries being run here.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen sorry for that,   I was assumed default that if i put left join/ right join then there would be some condition

Comment: I don't think the two will be the same in general.  The final join could discard records from `t3` or `t4` from each query in different ways.  Of course, if you have real tables and data, why not just try out the two queries?

Comment: Hi... @TimBiegeleisen Would you reconsider question I made some changes in **Query2**
and do not have any data/table regarding it

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen :- put one practical example with any sql fiddler or any other fiddler...its very useful for community..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are not the same. 
Ex. if we consider all the tables have the same number of rows, the first query returns less rows than the second one.

Comment: is second one contains duplicate data/row? @Mehrad Eslami

Comment: By running the first query you'll get Size of (T1 x T4)
In the second one you'll have (T1 x T3)
Depends on the data you may get duplicates but not necessarily